# ion-datetime with displayFormat mm not show value

Tags: javascript, ionic3

I have a demo [My Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-t8413v?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.html)
I tried add ion-datetime with displayformat="mm" and get value but it not show value or undefined
How I can custom ion-datetime only chose minute ( I don't care to hour because it will get by a ion-datetim other)

Please see my demo and help me.
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Initialize your variables with ISOStrings to use it with Ionic dateTime component

```
  this.valueMondayHhEnd= new Date().toISOString();
    this.valueMondayHhStart = new Date().toISOString();
    this.valueMondayMmStart = new Date().toISOString();
  this.valueMondayMmEnd = new Date().toISOString();
```